# Does the set of integral of all possible step functions under a curve have maximum element? Or it only has supremum with no maximum element?

Tags: integration, supremum-and-infimum

I am reading Apostol's Calculus. On page 74, section 1.17, it claims that every number in $S$ is less than every number in $T$. If I understand it correctly, that can only happen if $S$ doesn't have maximum element and $S$ doesn't have minimum element. The sets will have supremum and infimum. I'd like to confirm my understanding is correct.

Then, I'd would like to know which theorem tells us $S$ and $T$ cannot have maximum and minimum element respectively.

[image]

Comment: It should say "every number in $S$ is less than or equal to every number in $T$". If $f$ itself is a step function, we can take $s=f=t$ and get exact equality.

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily the case that $S$ or $T$ cannot have maximum/minimum respectively. For example when $f$ is a constant function. I think when they say less than (in your highlighted text) they meant less than or equal to.